# Want to click on a delete an element after searching for text from another div element

Tags: webdriver

I need to search for a keyword in the span element (having unique id) from class Z and then based on the matching criteria, I want to click on the delete icon under div of class A for id 'ucDaily_rptAMRoutineList_ctl01_icon_1'

Assuming I am searching for "Test", I would like to see working code on how to achieve this.

I have multiple class X here.

```
   <div class = "X">
        <div class="A">
            <div id="ucDaily_rptAMRoutineList_ctl01_1">
              <span class="B">
                <div id = "ucDaily_rptAMRoutineList_ctl01_icon_1">
                  <a>...</a>
                </div>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "Z">
          <strong>
          <span> Test </span>
          </strong>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: So, do you mean that if text inside <span> Test </span> == Test, then you want to click <a> ? I didnt get the thing what are you matching :)

Comment: Yup you are correct. I want to search for a text in the <span> and then click on delete in the anchor tag <a>. But here I have multiple parent div of class X. So I want to search for 'Test' and then click on the delete icon under <a>